# Can we connect to multiple Twitter accounts to ingest the data using Spark-Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I want to connect to multiple twitter accounts to ingesting the data using spark-scala. along with that can we connect to multiple apps from same twitter account.

Comment: have tried anything yet?

Comment: Thinking about Apache Nifi, Instead of Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, You can certainly do that.**

You will need multiple kafka topics for that. Here are the steps to fulfill your requirement.

1. Create mutiple kafka topics using different twitter account properties.
2. Create multiple kafka brokers, which can listen to the producers.
3. Create consumer/consumers as per your requirement to fetch the data from configured topics and ingest the data wherever you want.

Hope this helps!